# Scope of POROs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

It seems like when using only class methods on a PORO like a Service in a Rails app and called by controllers, that there is only one instance of the Service object created across all requests.

I know Rails creates new instances of Controllers and Models per request, but haven't seen anything documented about how Rails treats your own POROs.

What's your understanding?

Comment: Ruby doesn't really call them "PORO", it just calls them...objects. Everything in Ruby is an object, so there's really no need for a distinction like in other languages where objects are a special case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assume that most of your class instances has request scope - no matter if they're controllers, models or services (POROs). They can have broader scope if they're refenreced by global objects (e.g. rails configuration).

It's a bit different with the classes - they are loaded once when the application start and then they're in memory. If you use only class methods, it means you use classes, not instances, thus you have global scope.

Comment: Class objects exist for the lifespan of the process. The process could be one of many, and could be terminated after the request finishes. `rails s` is not an accurate representation of a real-world production environment.